# Post With token_id and Json

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Forgive me as I'm new to API driven development. I'm doing a front-end and back-end at the same time and ran into a snag.

On the back-end I accept URL encoded token_id that you may post to create a sessions. Goes like
http://someip:3000/sessions/create?**token_id=sometoken**
and works.

But now to create a post object the back-end expects a JSON object and a token_id. But reading some documentation for my front-end (android+retrofit) I understand that I can't URL encode a field (my token_id) and send a body as JSON.

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach. Which path should I take to receive the token_id and a json object at the same time on the back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that I can't URL encode a field (my token_id) and send a
>   body as JSON.

This is true if you are trying to send POST parameters, because those are sent as the body.  But you appear to be using query parameters which are part of the URL.  You can use query parameters and JSON body in the same request.  Your interface would be something like following, adjusting the body and return types for your particular case.

```
@POST("/sessions/create")
Call<Response> create(@Query("token_id") String tokenID, @Body MyBodyClass body);
```